# Android Custom Button (custom Text) using XML and TableLayout

Tags: android, xml, button, textview, android-tablelayout

I wanted to create a **Custom Button** with 4 independent `TextViews` in **XML** using **Android Studio**. (The button should have the option of a normal centered `TextView` which I can `setVisible()` when needed.)

However, I played around with the **layout heights**, but didn't find the proper solution yet. The goal is, that my `buttons.xml` will show the **Custom Button 6 times** on the right half of the screen (see `buttons.xml`) using a `TableLayout`.
This just worked perfectly when I used normal `Buttons` directly in the `TableLayout`. (See **UNDO Button** for reference, this is the correct size)

As soon as I tried to `<include>` my `custom_button.xml` within the `TableLayout`, they were either too big and one button would use more than 75% of the screen height (using `match_parent`), or the custom buttons were too small (using `wrap_content`).

Here are listed the mentioned `xml`-files, prepared for usage without `colors.xml`, `strings.xml` or `dimens.xml`:

---

#### **`activity_main.xml`**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.test.app.testapp.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

<!-- Other stuff like background image, toolbar and bottom info tableLayout -->

<include
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/buttons"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

#### **`buttons.xml`**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:background="#000000"

    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/text_01"
            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/text_02"
            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/text_03"
            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_03"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/text_04"
            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_04"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/text_05"
            />

        <!-- Wrap content makes the buttons too small, they should
        be evenly sized over the screen -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_05"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:enabled="false"

            android:background="#546752"
            android:text="UNDO"

            android:id="@+id/button_07"/>

        <!-- I tried match_parent for height here but it didn't work  -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_06"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />

    </TableRow>    
</TableLayout>
```

---

#### **`custom_button.xml`**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/custom_button"
    >

    <!-- I think wrap_content is wrong, but match_parent makes all of
    those too big in the buttons.xml -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="#55546752"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_button_normal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TEXT"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <!-- How to make this tablelayout the same height like the two
    things above??

    How to CENTER the 4 TextViews not just horizontally, but also
    vertically?? -->
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_table">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_button_label_1"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_button_label_2"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_button_label_3"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_button_label_4"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

#### Output:

You can see, the first 5 buttons on the right site are too small and the custom `TextViews` are not aligned correctly (vertical center).
The sixth button on the right site uses `match_parent` for height and has a mixed size of being correct, but it's content is still too small (due to `wrap_content`).
The only `Button` being displayed correctly is the UNDO-`Button`.

(Give me reputation so I can include images directly):
[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/GceRNZ6.png)

If you can provide a solution for a custom `Button` like this one, and the `TableLayout` I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for some random guy from the Uni for the solution!!

---

## Solution

---

#### **`buttons.xml`**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:background="#000000"

    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/text_01"
            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            />


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/text_02"

            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/text_03"
            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_03"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/text_04"
            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_04"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/lastTableRow"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/text_05"
            />

        <!-- Wrap content makes the buttons too small, they should
        be evenly sized over the screen -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_05"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".16666666">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:background="#546752"

            android:text="UNDO"
            android:id="@+id/button_07"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_06"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/custom_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"

            />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

---

#### **`custom_button.xml`**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/custom_button"
    >

    <!-- I think wrap_content is wrong, but match_parent makes all of
    those too big in the buttons.xml -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="#55546752"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_button_normal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TEXT"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <!-- How to make this tablelayout the same height like the two
    things above??

    How to CENTER the 4 TextViews not just horizontally, but also
    vertically?? -->
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_table">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_button_label_1"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_button_label_2"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight=".5"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_button_label_3"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_button_label_4"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Finally, it looks like this:

[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/I1zCYrp.png)